# ColorBox Onclose function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I am trying to open a new colorbox window when one is closed.

I'm using this code:

```
$(".inline").colorbox({
    inline: true, 
    width: "50%", 
    escKey: false,
    onClose: function() {
        $('#newWindow').show();
    }
```

If there anything wrong with this code?

Comment: Is the missing brace and bracket at the end just a mistake when you copied and pasted?

Comment: If that's all of your code you're missing some closures at the end "})". A little more code and a link would be handy

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Description

Assuming your using [jack moore's colorbox jQuery plugin](http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) you have to change `onClose` to `onClosed` and use `open:true`.
**And you always have to close the function.**

Check out the [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/yBQj7/).

### Sample

**Html**

```
<div class="firstColorBox">first</div>
<div class="secondColorBox">second</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".firstColorBox").colorbox({
    inline:true, 
    width:"50%", 
    escKey:false,
    onClosed:function(){
        // open the other colorBox
        $(".secondColorBox").colorbox({
                inline:true, 
                width:"50%", 
                escKey:false,
                open:true
        });     
    }
});
```

### More Information

- **[jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/yBQj7/)**
- [jack moore's colorbox jQuery plugin](http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)

### Update

Comment: Yes I'm using that plugin but #newWindow doesn't open after I close the window

Answer (score 3):

'onClose' should be 'onClosed'

See the reference here: http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend use the event handlers that come with colorbox:

```
$(document).one('cbox_closed', function () { 
    $(".secondColorBox").colorbox({...}); 
}
```

This will allow the javascript on the page to run.  I was having issues running  tags on the second popup and this solved the issue.

The function one will only trigger the event once so you can close the second popup.